# Extracting a Point From Multiple Data Frames Within a List

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I am trying to isolate one point in the same location (same column and row) from 1000 data frames. Each data frame has the same 8 columns with varying amounts of rows (at least one)- and I only need the points from the first row for now. These data frames are within a list created with the `lapply` function. Here is how I did that:

```
list <- list.files(pattern=".aei")
files <- lapply(list, read.table, ...)
```

Now, I need to isolate points from each data frame in Row 1 and Column 2. I was able to do this for one data frame with the following code:

```
a <- data.frame(files[1])[1,2]
```

However, I can't get this to work for all 1000 files. I've tried several pieces of code, such as:

```
all <- data.frame(files[1:999])[1,2]
```

```
all<- lapply(files data.frame)[1,2]
```

```
all<- lapply(files, data.frame[1,2])
```

and even two different for loops:

```
for(i in files [[1:999]]) {
    list(files[1:999])[1,2]
}
```

```
for(i in files [[1:999]]) {
    data.frame(files[1:999])[1,2]
}
```

Are any of these methods on the right track or are they completely wrong? I've been stuck on this for awhile and seem to have hit a complete dead end regarding any other ideas. Please let me know of any suggestions you may have!

Comment: Please make the question more [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a anonymous function (lambda function) to extrac the element

```
lapply(files, function(x) x[1,2])
```

The `read.table` already gives a `data.frame`, so there is no need to wrap with `data.frame`